# Is there a way to react to every message ever sent with discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

I wanna use an bot to react to every single message in an channel using discord.js f.e. i got an emoji contest channel and i wanna ad an ✅  and an ✖ reaction on every post in there
ofc, all the unnecesary messages are cleaned up so that there are like 50 messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Fetch the messages already sent in a channel with [`TextChannel.fetchMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages).
- Iterate through the [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection).
- Add reactions with [`Message.react()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=react).
- When a new message is sent in the channel, you should also add the reactions.

```js
const emojiChannelID = 'ChannelIDHere';
```

```js
client.on('ready', async () => {
  try {
    const channel = client.channels.get(emojiChannelID);
    if (!channel) return console.error('Invalid ID or missing channel.');

    const messages = await channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 100 });

    for (const [id, message] of messages) {
      await message.react('✅');
      await message.react('✖');
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  if (message.channel.id === emojiChannelID) {
    try {
      await message.react('✅');
      await message.react('✖');
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
});
```

In this code, you'll notice I'm using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop rather than [`Map.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach). The reasoning behind this is that the latter will simply call the methods and move on. This would cause any rejected promises *not* to be caught. I've also used [async/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) style rather than `then()` chains which could easily get messy.

Comment: got it working like that, thx, but im pretty new to js coding, what does this => i figure it doesnt mean sammerl or equal than

Comment: `=>` is actually part of the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax. `<=` and `>=` are [relational operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Relational_operators)s. `=>` and `>=` can be easily confused, but they're very different.

Comment: can you develop on the rejected promises part? I used the `Map.forEach()` in one of my previous answer and didn't think/know about it. You're talking about the `message.react` promise, aren't you? Because if a promise if rejected, the `forEach` will stop so it will be stopped and go in the catch as you for, no?

Comment: The way `forEach()` works, no. It simply invokes the Promise and continues to iterate. By the time it's done, Promises will be still be in their pending state. Even if you use the `await` keyword, it's not going to be effective towards this issue. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop/45006966) for a much more thorough explanation of the workings and the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel

you can use [`fetchMessages`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages)
 to get all messages from a specific channel, which then returns a collection of `Message`

Then you can use [`.react`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=react) function to apply your reactions to this collection of message by iterating over it and calling `.react` on each.

Edit:

```
channelToFetch.fetchMessages()
    .then(messages => {
        messages.tap(message => {
            message.react(`CHARACTER CODE OR EMOJI CODE`).then(() => {
              // Do what ever or use async/await syntax if you don't care 
                 about Promise handling
            })
        })
    })
```